# Addressing issue in reusing appium/android driver and webdriver based methods

Tags: java, android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

We have a current implementation of a method called `click(WebElement element)` which has the following code

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("Grid URL"), capabilities);
public void click(WebElement element) {
    element = driver.findElement(By.id("some id"));
    element.click();
}
```

The above click method is used to click an element in `Firefox` browser.

Now if I use `Appium` in the same framework, I also have a `click` method to click an element in the Android or iOS platform. So the code would be

```
AndroidDriver anroidDriver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
public void click(WebElement element) {
    element = driver.findElement(By.id("some id"));
    element.click();
}
```

As you can see both `click` methods are same. What I want to do is re-use the code. I could do

```
AndroidDriver anroidDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

But the problem here is it won't work for `iOS` platform. I tried doing this

```
WebDriver driver = (AndroidDriver) RemoteWebDriver(....);
```

But the problem here is there are a few methods that `AndroidDriver` has which is not in `WebDriver`. How is everyone else solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

AndriodDriver and IOSDriver are implementation of Remotewebdriver. From the question I see that you want to reuse the instantiation of the object as a code that is reusable, which you cannot.

What you do is use

```
Webdriver driver = new AndriodDriver(...) or Webdriver driver = new IOSDriver.
```

Since you driver is base class variable pointing to instantiation of subclasses, driver variable will work for both.

For example :

```
driver.click()
```

would work for both. You can't reuse the codelines that are in instatiation, but by using base type reference variable you can use benefits of polymorphism

Comment: But if I do that I won't be able to use a lot of methods like `swipe()`, `tap()` etc because this is specifically available only in `AndroidDriver` or `IOSDriver`. This is work only if I do `AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(...)`

Answer (score -1):

Try below method:

```
WebDriver driver;
AppiumDriver<MobileElement> androidDriver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://"), desiredCapabilities);
driver = androidDriver;
```

In this way, you can access both AndroidDriver and WebDriver methods.
Kindly let me know if you got any other solution. Thanks.